# Append cell value in a df depending on a conditiontion

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame "New_data" structured like this

| Index | ID | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 001 | abc |
| 1 | 001 | def |
| 2 | 002 | ghi |
| 3 | 002 | lmn |
| 4 | 002 | opq |
| 5 | 003 | rst |
| 6 | 001 | uvz |

As you can see the column "ID" contains multiple IDs that are equal. I would like to create an additional column ('Merged content') that, in each row, contains the values of all the "Content" cells with the same value in the "ID" column. I would like something like this:

| Index | ID | Content | Merged content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 001 | abc | abc def uvz |
| 1 | 001 | def | abc def uvz |
| 2 | 002 | ghi | ghi lmn opq |
| 3 | 002 | lmn | ghi lmn opq |
| 4 | 002 | opq | ghi lmn opq |
| 5 | 003 | rst | rst |
| 6 | 001 | uvz | abc def uvz |

I have tried with the for loops but I was not successful.
I have created a new df `num` with unique values for the ID column to iterate over them and about the problem of duplicated indexes but still, I was not able to solve my problem.

This is the code I have tried to apply:

```
for i in range(len(num)):
    ID = num.iloc[i,0]
    for j in range(len(new_data)):
        ID_data = new_data.iloc[j,index]
        if ID == ID_data.iloc[j, 0]:
            new_data['Merged Content'] = new_data['Merged Content'].append(new_data['Content'])
```

I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'iloc'`
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I could come up with was by running `groupby` on the `ID`, and then merging the two frames again:

```
import pandas as pd

# df = pd.read_clipboard()

merged_col = df.groupby("ID").agg(merged=pd.NamedAgg("Content", " ".join))
res = df.merge(merged_col, how="left", on="ID")

print(res)
```

First, I group the original dataframe by "ID", and us `" ".join` as the aggregation function. This yields:

```
          merged
ID              
1    abc def uvz
2    ghi lmn opq
3            rst
```

Then I merge that table with the original on `ID`:

```
   Index  ID Content       merged
0      0   1     abc  abc def uvz
1      1   1     def  abc def uvz
2      2   2     ghi  ghi lmn opq
3      3   2     lmn  ghi lmn opq
4      4   2     opq  ghi lmn opq
5      5   3     rst          rst
6      6   1     uvz  abc def uvz
```

Generally try to avoid running a loop over all records in a dataframe. They tend to be much slower than operations acting on the whole column. The reason is because a loop runs in regular Python, looking at every element, whereas the column operations are typically optimized code using the libraries behind `pandas` and `numpy`.

Comment: GREAT solution! I was not thinking about using groupby! Actually I add to convert the text in "content" as str because of some problems in the original dataset, then it worked perfectly. Thank you